# password and confirm password checker not working properly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

It works great when i used span tag to display message.
but when i used bootstrap popover to display whether the passwords matched or not it is getting some delay to display when the passwords are matched.
did i use the popover wrong?

```
<input required type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" class="form-control mb-1 password" style="width:500px">
<input required type="password" name="cpassword" data-toggle="popover" title="" data-content="" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="form-control cpassword" style="width:500px">

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    passCheck();
  });

  function passCheck() {    
    $('.password,.cpassword').on('keyup', function() {
      var pass = $(".password").val();
      var cpass = $('.cpassword').val();
      if (pass == cpass) {
        $('.cpassword').attr("data-content", "Password matched");

      } else {
        $('.cpassword').attr("data-content", "Password is not matched");

      }
    });
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the following code as the last statement in your passCheck function:

```
$("[data-toggle='popover']").popover('show');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tshenolo/apshzxg9/51/